# Resetting websocket

Tags: java, sockets, web, websocket

I'm writing program that communicates through web sockets and sends serialized objects. I have problem in situation, when connection between server and client is lost. I get this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1286)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1231)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1577)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
at common.WebSocketServer.sendResponse(WebSocketServer.java:103)
at common.WebSocketServer.listen(WebSocketServer.java:86)
at common.WebSocketServer.main(WebSocketServer.java:50)
```

When I use method socket.isConnected() to check, if server should abandon this client, it returns true (why?), even after closing socket and opening again it is still opened. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible causes but the most common are that you had written to a connection that had already been closed by the peer, or that the peer closed the connection while it still had pending data to read. Both being application protocol errors.

`Socket.isConnected()` tells you about the state of the socket. Not of the connection.